# Quaternion addition like 3ds/gmax does with it's quats

Tags: quaternions

A project I'm working on needs a function which mimics 3ds/gmax's quaternion addition. A test case of (quat 1 2 3 4)+(quat 3 5 7 9) should equal (quat 20 40 54 2). These quats are in xyzw.
So, I figure it's basic algebra, given the clean numbers. It's got to be something like this multiply function, since it doesn't involve sin/cos:

```
    const quaternion &operator *=(const quaternion &q)      
    {
        float x= v.x, y= v.y, z= v.z, sn= s*q.s - v*q.v;
        v.x= y*q.v.z - z*q.v.y + s*q.v.x + x*q.s;
        v.y= z*q.v.x - x*q.v.z + s*q.v.y + y*q.s;
        v.z= x*q.v.y - y*q.v.x + s*q.v.z + z*q.s;
        s= sn;
        return *this;
    }
```

[source](http://willperone.net/Code/quaternion.php)

But, I don't understand how sn= s*q.s - v*q.v is supposed to work. s is a float, v is vector. Multiply vectors and add to float? 
I'm not even sure which terms of direction/rotation/orientation these values represent, but if the function satisfies the quat values above, it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Turns out to be known as multiplication. Addition is multiplication. Up is sideways. Not confusing at all :/

```
fn qAdd q1 q2 = (
x1=q1.x
y1=q1.y
z1=q1.z
w1=q1.w
x2=q2.x
y2=q2.y
z2=q2.z
w2=q2.w

W = (W1 * W2) - (X1 * X2) - (Y1 * Y2) - (Z1 * Z2)
X = (W1 * X2) + (X1 * W2) + (Y1 * Z2) - (Z1 * Y2)
Y = (W1 * Y2) + (Y1 * W2) + (Z1 * X2) - (X1 * Z2)
Z = (W1 * Z2) + (Z1 * W2) + (X1 * Y2) - (Y1 * X2)

return (quat x y z w)
```

)

Swapping q1 & q2 yields different results, quite neither like addition nor multiplication.

[source](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/quaternion_8h_source.html)

Comment: If you want to "add up" rotations (which is the main use of quaternions), then you need to multiply their quaternion representations.  If you apply two different rotations to an object, the final result is order-dependent.  That's why swapping the order makes a difference.